# How to delete rows in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

Very new to python and Tkinter.

I'm trying to allow a user to enter a number which will then determine the number of lines that are displayed. However when a new number is submitted that is less than the previous number, old row are not deleted.

Thanks in advance!

Example Code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()

def input_count():
    try:
        user_submission=int(user_text.get())
    except:
        wrong_submission=tk.Label(root,  text="That isn't a number, try again!", justify = tk.LEFT, padx = 20)
        wrong_submission.grid(column=0 , row=1)
    else:
        for num in range(0,user_submission):
            old_row=2
            new_row=old_row+(2*num)
            extra_new_row= new_row + 1
            animal_check=tk.Label(root,  text='Enter an animal', justify = tk.LEFT, padx = 20)
            animal_check.grid(column=0 , row=new_row)
            animal_text = Entry(root, width= 50)
            animal_text.grid(column=1, row=new_row)
            colour_check=tk.Label(root,  text='Enter a colour', justify = tk.LEFT, padx = 20)
            colour_check.grid(column=0 , row=extra_new_row)
            colour_text = Entry(root, width= 50)
            colour_text.grid(column=1, row=extra_new_row)



user_label=tk.Label(root, text='Enter a number', justify = tk.LEFT, padx = 20)
user_label.grid(column=0 , row=0)
user_text= Entry(root, width= 50)
user_text.grid(column=1, row=0)
user_submit=Button(root,text="SUBMIT", command=input_count)
user_submit.grid(column=2,row=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There's a much bigger bug in your code: how do you plan to get the user response out? You are throwing out all the references. Once you fix that you will find you can use those same references and the `destroy` method to remove them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

You can split your root window into two frames, one that contains the user entry, the other one that contains all the new lines. Then you can use the method 'grid_forget' on the second frame to delete it and create a new frame each time the user submit a number of lines.

```
import os, sys
from Tkinter import *


root = tk.Tk()

def input_count():
    try:
        user_submission=int(user_text.get())
    except:
        wrong_submission=tk.Label(frame_top,  text="That isn't a number, try again!", justify = tk.LEFT, padx = 20)
        wrong_submission.grid(column=0 , row=1)
    else:
        try:
            frame_bottom.grid_forget()
        except:
            pass
        frame_bottom = tk.Frame(root)
        frame_bottom.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        for num in range(0,user_submission):
            old_row=2
            new_row=old_row+(2*num)
            extra_new_row= new_row + 1
            animal_check=tk.Label(frame_bottom, text='Enter an animal', justify = tk.LEFT, padx = 20)
            animal_check.grid(column=0, row=new_row)
            animal_text = Entry(frame_bottom, width= 50)
            animal_text.grid(column=1, row=new_row)
            colour_check=tk.Label(frame_bottom,  text='Enter a colour', justify = tk.LEFT, padx = 20)
            colour_check.grid(column=0, row=extra_new_row)
            colour_text = Entry(frame_bottom, width= 50)
            colour_text.grid(column=1, row=extra_new_row)

frame_top = tk.Frame(root)
frame_top.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

frame_bottom = tk.Frame(root)
frame_bottom.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

user_label=tk.Label(frame_top, text='Enter a number', justify = tk.LEFT, padx = 20)
user_label.grid(column=0 , row=0)
user_text= Entry(frame_top, width= 50)
user_text.grid(column=1, row=0)
user_submit=Button(frame_top,text="SUBMIT", command=input_count)
user_submit.grid(column=2,row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code has several issues. Most glaring: your code deletes any previously entered information when resizing.

Comment: You're an absolute saint. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a container to keep a reference to your rows. To keep things neat, lets put all the components of a row into a class. Then we can have a `destroy()` method that destroys all of the row, and a `get()` method that gets the result from the row. We'll make a global list called "current_rows" that keeps all the rows that are currently displayed. We can add to that list to add rows, and remove from that list to delete rows.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from tkMessageBox import showerror

class Mgene:
    def __init__(self, master):
        columns, rows = master.grid_size()
        self.animal_check=tk.Label(master,  text='Enter an animal', justify = tk.LEFT, padx = 20)
        self.animal_check.grid(column=0 , row=rows)
        self.animal_text = tk.Entry(master, width= 50)
        self.animal_text.grid(column=1, row=rows)
        self.colour_check=tk.Label(master,  text='Enter a colour', justify = tk.LEFT, padx = 20)
        self.colour_check.grid(column=0 , row=rows+1)
        self.colour_text = tk.Entry(master, width= 50)
        self.colour_text.grid(column=1, row=rows+1)

    def destroy(self):
        self.animal_check.destroy()
        self.animal_text.destroy()
        self.colour_check.destroy()
        self.colour_text.destroy()

    def get(self):
        return self.animal_text.get(), self.colour_text.get()

current_rows = []
def input_count():
    try:
        user_submission=int(user_text.get())
    except:
        showerror("Error", "That isn't a number, try again!")
    else:
        # add any rows needed
        for num in range(len(current_rows)-1, user_submission):
            current_rows.append(Mgene(root))

        # remove any rows needed
        while len(current_rows) > user_submission:
            current_rows.pop().destroy()

def get_answers():
    for row in current_rows:
        print row.get()

root = tk.Tk()

user_label=tk.Label(root, text='Enter a number', justify = tk.LEFT, padx = 20)
user_label.grid(column=0 , row=0)
user_text= tk.Entry(root, width= 50)
user_text.grid(column=1, row=0)
user_submit=tk.Button(root,text="SUBMIT", command=input_count)
user_submit.grid(column=2,row=0)
user_get=tk.Button(root,text="print answers", command=get_answers)
user_get.grid(column=2,row=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Note this gives the extra advantage that when the time comes to get the user data out, we have a nice list of rows we can iterate over.

Comment: Above and beyond! Thanks!